# How to input distance matrix in SPSS to do Twostep cluster analysis?

Tags: matrix, cluster-analysis, distance, spss

I already have a distance matrix (1609*1609) and each distance is between 0~1. I want to cluster 1609 items into natural groups by using Twostep cluster in SPSS. I want to use the distance matrix as input for Twostep cluster analysis. How to modify the syntax to do that? Or I cannot do it?

```
DATASET ACTIVATE dataname1.
TWOSTEP CLUSTER
  /CATEGORICAL VARIABLES=ROWTYPE VARNAME
  /CONTINUOUS VARIABLES=A1 to A1609 *Ignore the A2 to A1608 here.
  /DISTANCE LIKELIHOOD
  /NUMCLUSTERS AUTO 15 BIC
  /HANDLENOISE 0
  /MEMALLOCATE 64
  /CRITERIA INITHRESHOLD(0) MXBRANCH(8) MXLEVEL(3)
  /VIEWMODEL DISPLAY=YES
  /SAVE VARIABLE=TSC_4920.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of that vaguely-documented "twostep" clustering, it needs to compute the mean of points.

Then it *cannot* be used with a distance matrix. Consider using ELKI, sklearn, or R instead. As a plus, they are open source, so you can actually *check* what they are doing, and *customize* them if e.g. they would not allow a distance matrix somewhere. That is a very big feature, being open source.

Comment: Thanks for the information. In fact, I already try `Nbclust` in R, but it seems using different methods (not AIC or BIC) to determine the clusters numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The twostep algorithm, as well as all the others in Statistics, is fully documented in the algorithms manual available from the Help menu.

Comment: Sorry, I was addressing only the issue about the algorithm. TWOSTEP does not provide for starting with an existing distance matrix.  The CLUSTER procedure, for hierarchical clustering does accept matrix input.

Comment: Don't be sorry. That is a good suggestion. I already let SPSS read matrix input to do hierarchical cluster, but I cannot do the same thing in TwoStep cluster analysis. Thanks for response again.